# Как создать функцию для упрощения объявления переменных LiveData для Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, livedata

Для объявления переменных LiveData нужно постоянно писать шаблонный код

```
private val _score = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val score: LiveData<Int>
    get() = _score
```

Как это можно упростить? Чтобы не копипастить и не забывать каждый раз заменять переменную с подчеркиванием, без подчеркивания и при необходимости менять тип в 2х местах. Хотелось что то типа ОбъявитьПеременную(имя, Тип)

Comment: Никак, это стандартная конструкция [backing-properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties)

Comment: Это, конечно, не решение, но может немного упростить жизнь. Если вы используете `Android Studio` или `Intellij IDEA` - создайте `LiveTemplate` [такой](https://pastebin.com/TJLCJBkj)